# Establish inequality from matrix power series

Tags: matrices, inequality, power-series

Define the following $J \times J$ matrices:

$\boldsymbol{A}$, with $a_{ij} \in [0,1]$ and row stochastic:$\qquad\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{J}a_{ij}=1$;

$\boldsymbol{B}$, diagonal matrix with $b_{ii} \in (0,1)$;

$\boldsymbol{C}$, diagonal matrix with $c_{ii} \in (0,1)$;

and $J \times 1$ vector $\boldsymbol{e}_{i}$ with zero entries everywhere except for index $i$, which has value $1$.

Let

$\displaystyle d_{ik}=\frac{\boldsymbol{e}_{i}'(\mathbb{I}_{J}-BA)^{-1}C^{-1}(\mathbb{I}_{J}-BA)^{-1}\boldsymbol{e}_{k}}{\boldsymbol{e}_{i}'(\mathbb{I}_{J}-BA)^{-1}\boldsymbol{e}_{k}}$

Is it possible to show that $d_{ii} \geq d_{ik}$ (e.g., by developing the power series of the matrix inverse)?

Comment: The ingredients to prove this can be found in

Zeng, L. (2001): “A property of the Leontief inverse and its applications to comparative static analysis” Economic Systems Research, 13, 299–315.